# Angular - pass additional form data to the server

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-controller

I have a basic Angular form with `prod_name`, `prod_desc`, `prod_price`, those of course I want to send to the server when form is submitted.

However I want to send additional peace of data and I don't want to make hidden input field for that.

So stripped version of form looks something like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(productForm.value)">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Product Name" formControlName="prod_name"
           [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">

  </mat-form-field>

 <!-- Additional two form fields omitted for clarity -->

  <div class="button-row">
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!productForm.valid" mat-flat-button color="primary"><mat-icon>save</mat-icon></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Basically it invokes `onFormSubmit()` and passes to it `productForm.value`.

This is what controller looks like, stripped with only necessary data for clarity:

```
@Component({
//...
})
export class ProductAddComponent implements OnInit {

  productForm: FormGroup;
  updated_at: Date = null;

  constructor(private router: Router, private api: ApiService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'prod_name' : [null, Validators.required],
      'prod_desc' : [null, Validators.required],
      'prod_price' : [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    // Here I want to add current date as well to the form data before sending it
    this.api.addProduct(form)
      .subscribe(res => {
          let id = res.id;
          this.router.navigate(['/product-details', id]);
      }, err => {
          console.log(err);
      });
  }

}
```

Within `onFormSubmit()` function I want to pass a current date to the server as well.
Hidden field in the form template is not the option.
I want to do it in the `onFormSubmit()` function before calling the service but I'm stuck.

I would appreciate help as to how basically set additional data along with the form data, for example date and sent it to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the form data and then add anything you want to it.

```
  onFormSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const dataForSubmit = {...form.value}; // copies the form data into a new variable
    dataForSubmit.otherProperty = 'what ever you want'; // add whatever data is needed
    this.api.addProduct(dataForSubmit)
      .subscribe(res => {
          let id = res.id;
          this.router.navigate(['/product-details', id]);
      }, err => {
          console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

In my applications, I often have an interface defined for all of the data. I get that data into that interface and only copy the fields I want to the form. Then on a save, copy the changes from the form onto the original object.

**Interface**

```
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode: string;
}
```

Of course, the system id does not appear in the UI.

**Component code**

```
// Update the data on the form
// after a get
this.productForm.patchValue({
  productName: this.product.productName,
  productCode: this.product.productCode
});

// The save
  saveProduct(): void {
    if (this.productForm.valid) {
       // Copies any changed form values over the original product values
       const p = { ...this.product, ...this.productForm.value };

       // Call the http service put to save the data `p`
    }
  }
```

Comment: Solution is much more straightforward and simpler than I thought. I got lost in searching Angular objects and some function for that. Maybe also array notation can be used to add data to the object without copying it? Or is it better to copy? Thanks for the answer and also for the design-pattern advice!

Comment: The form object itself (productForm) has a *lot* of extra stuff on it. You can output it to the console to look. You are much better off just copying the values from that object onto another object and editing that.

Comment: Yes, actually onFormSubmit() function gets passed only values to it, it looks like this in the template "(ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(productForm.value)", this also passes smaller object to the function, since JavaScript passes arguments to function by value. I know it's not much of a speed improvement but one of those tiny things.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that. What threw me was this: `form: NgForm` as the data type.

Comment: I have removed that now, it is a leftover code from someone else and it threw me also in the wrong track of searching some function in the `NgForm` for adding new data, not realizing it is actually plain vanilla JavaScript object.